# Can I enable/disable a network connection from the command-line or MS-Dos?

Tags: batch-file

I want to enable/disable a network connection from the command-line in Windows 8.

```
netsh interface set interface “Local Area Connection” DISABLED
```

To enable the interface, you'd then run:

```
netsh interface set interface “Local Area Connection” ENABLED
```

When I try this, it generates an error message which states that "no more data is available".

Comment: You can try [devcon](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1886-enable-disable-a-device-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

`netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=DISABLED`

Answer (score 3):

This may be enough for you if you are using DHCP.

Disable:

```
ipconfig /release *
```

Enable:

```
ipconfig /renew
```

Comment: Any way to combine the two to toggle it using 1 batch file?

Answer (score 0):

Technical Note: There are several names associated with a network adapter on Windows API level, occurring in Struct PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES

PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES::AdapterName
PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES::Description
PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES::FriendlyName

`FriendlyName` is a unique logical name like "WLAN 3", generated by the system
and the one displayed with `ipconfig` and required in `netsh interface ...`.

`Description` is the tag displayed with `ipconfig /all`