# How to write a script that will turn restart my internet connection if its weak?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wifi

I am living in a guest house and my landlord is kindly letting me use his WiFi, however, my connection strength constantly toggles from good (5 bars) to bad (2 bars). Additionally, it seems that my browser freezes whenever it reaches 2 bars two, which is really weird (or maybe a weirder coincidence) and the only way to unfreeze it is by disconnecting my connection on my laptop and reconnecting again.

I know this may not be the best or permanent fix, but just out of curiosity, is there a way to write a script that will automatically toggle my connection off and on if my WiFi connection becomes weak? If so, how can I do this?

If it matters, my OS is Windows 8.1.

Comment: As you did not show any research efforts, I will not place any code here... 
However I will give you [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664830/storing-wifi-signal-strength-as-a-variable) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485848/can-i-enable-disable-a-network-connection-from-the-command-line-or-ms-dos) post to read.

Try to build from that on your own and come back with more specific questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a nice **[batch script to automatically repair LAN connection](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24297554/batch-file-to-automatically-repair-LAN-connection.html)**  on the net so, i share it with you, and hope that can help you !

```dos
@echo off
cls & echo.
echo               __       ___     
echo              /\ \__  /'___\ __
echo   ___      __\ \ ,_\/\ \__//\_\   __  _  
echo /' _ `\  /'__`\ \ \/\ \ ,__\/\ \ /\ \/'\ 
echo /\ \/\ \/\  __/\ \ \_\ \ \_/\ \ \\/^>  ^</
echo \ \_\ \_\ \____\\ \__\\ \_\  \ \_\/\_/\_\
echo  \/_/\/_/\/____/ \/__/ \/_/   \/_/\//\/_/
echo.
echo NetFix v2.0c by Giovanni Heward (g@utahjrs.com)
echo.
echo Performs actions similiar to the network repair option and more!
echo See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289256
echo.
echo [Optional Switches]
echo /w   - winsock reset (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259) - requires reboot
echo /t   - tcp/ip reset  (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357) - requires reboot
echo /d   - debug mode
echo.
echo Note: This script requires elevated privileges to operate properly.
echo.
if [%1]==[/?] goto :eof
for /f %%d in ('date/t') do set d=%%d & for /f %%t in ('time/t') do set t=%%t
echo ---[NetFix runtime: %d% %t%]--->>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log

set p=Releasing IP address
if exist %windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe (
echo %p% & title %p% & echo ---[%p%]--- >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
%windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe /release 1>>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
if [%1]==[/d] echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel%==0 echo Successfully released IP...
if %errorlevel%==1 echo ERROR: Failed to release IP... check netfix.log
if %errorlevel%==3 echo NOTE: An IP address has not yet been associated with the network endpoint.
) else (echo ERROR: failed to release ip address - unable to locate %windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe)
if [%1]==[/d] pause

set p=Flushing ARP cache
if exist %windir%\system32\netsh.exe (
echo. & echo %p% & title %p% & echo ---[%p%]--- >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
%windir%\system32\netsh.exe interface ip delete arpcache 1>>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
if [%1]==[/d] echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel%==0 echo Successfully flushed ARP cache...
if %errorlevel%==1 (echo ERROR: Failed to flush ARP cache... check netfix.log)
) else (
if exist %windir%\system32\arp.exe (
%windir%\system32\arp.exe -d * 1>>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
if [%1]==[/d] echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel%==0 echo Successfully flushed ARP cache...
if %errorlevel%==1 (echo ERROR: Failed to flush ARP cache... check netfix.log)
) else (echo ERROR: failed to flush arp cache - unable to locate %windir%\system32\netsh.exe or %windir%\system32\arp.exe))
if [%1]==[/d] pause

set p=Reloading NetBIOS name cache
if exist %windir%\system32\nbtstat.exe (
echo. & echo %p% & title %p% & echo ---[%p%]--- >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
%windir%\system32\nbtstat.exe -R 1>>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
if [%1]==[/d] echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel%==0 echo Successfully reloaded NetBIOS name cache...
if %errorlevel%==1 (echo ERROR: Failed to reload NetBIOS name cache... check netfix.log)
) else (
echo ERROR: Failed to reload netbios name cache - unable to locate %windir%\system32\nbtstat.exe)
if [%1]==[/d] pause

set p=Sending NetBIOS name update
if exist %windir%\system32\nbtstat.exe (
echo. & echo %p% & title %p% & echo ---[%p%]--- >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
%windir%\system32\nbtstat.exe -RR 1>>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
if [%1]==[/d] echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
) else (echo ERROR: Failed to send netbios name update - unable to locate %windir%\system32\nbtstat.exe)
if [%1]==[/d] pause

set p=Flushing DNS cache
if exist %windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe (
echo. & echo %p% & title %p% & echo ---[%p%]--- >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
%windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe /flushdns 1>>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
if [%1]==[/d] echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
) else (echo ERROR: Failed to flush dns cache - unable to locate %windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe)
if [%1]==[/d] pause

if [%1]==[/w] goto :winsock
if [%1]==[/t] goto :ipreset
goto :cont

:ipreset
set p=Resetting TCP/IP
if exist %windir%\system32\netsh.exe (
echo. & echo %p% & title %p% & echo ---[%p%]--- >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
%windir%\system32\netsh.exe int ip reset %userprofile%\desktop\netreset.log 1>>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
if [%1]==[/d] echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Successfully reset TCP/IP
echo Note: This fix requires a system restart... run "shutdown /a" to abort.
if exist %windir%\system32\shutdown.exe %windir%\system32\shutdown.exe /r
)
if %errorlevel%==1 (echo ERROR: Failed to reset tcp/ip... check netfix.log)
) else (echo ERROR: Failed to reset tcp/ip - unable to locate %windir%\system32\netsh.exe)
goto :end

:winsock
set p=Resetting Winsock
if exist %windir%\system32\netsh.exe (
echo. & echo %p% & title %p% & echo ---[%p%]--- >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
%windir%\system32\netsh.exe winsock reset 1>>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
if [%1]==[/d] echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Successfully reset winsock
echo Note: This fix requires a system restart... run "shutdown /a" to abort.
if exist %windir%\system32\shutdown.exe %windir%\system32\shutdown.exe /r
)
if %errorlevel%==1 (echo Failed to reset winsock... check netfix.log)
) else (echo ERROR: Failed to reset winsock - unable to locate %windir%\system32\netsh.exe)
if [%1]==[/d] pause

:cont
set p=Renewing IP address
if exist %windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe (
echo. & echo %p% & title %p% & echo ---[%p%]--- >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
%windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe /renew 1>>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
if [%1]==[/d] echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
) else (echo ERROR: Failed to renew IP address - unable to locate %windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe)
if [%1]==[/d] pause

set p=Registering DNS name
if exist %windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe (
echo. & echo %p% & title %p% & echo ---[%p%]--- >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
%windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe /registerdns 1>>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
if [%1]==[/d] echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
) else (echo ERROR: Failed to register DNS name - unable to locate %windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe)

:end
if exist %windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe (
echo ---[ip configuration]--- >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
%windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe /all >>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log 2>>&1
)
echo. & echo Network Repair Complete! & echo ---[Finished: %d% %t%]--->>%userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
set p= & title NetFix v2.0b by Giovanni Heward (g@utahjrs.com) complete! & set t= & set d=
::**********************************************************************************
::Added by Hackoo to convert log file to Unicode output on 06/10/2016
Cmd /U /C Type %userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log > %userprofile%\desktop\netfix.txt
If exist %userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log Del %userprofile%\desktop\netfix.log
Start "" %userprofile%\desktop\netfix.txt
::**********************************************************************************
pause & exit
```

Comment: Could you please also share the source?

Comment: @aschipfl i edit my answser and i added the link where i were found this script ;)

Comment: @Hackoo how do i elevate my privileges to make the script work properly?